# Redash metadata DB migrate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, redash

I am using Redash v5.0.0 and PostgreSQL for metadata in an EC2 instance. I can create Redash v8.x container on ECS and PostgreSQL on RDS, however how can I migrate metadata in EC2 for Redash v5 to RDS for redash v8?

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow is for programming questions. For Database administration related queries use https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, I didnt know it. Thank you.